# Running Github Action When PR is raised from specific branch name to specific branch name?

Tags: github, github-actions

We have a public SDK repo for which I am writing multiple github workflows. One such workflow includes Generating a Release SDK(minified, encoded with private keys) when a PR is raised from `develop` to `master`. another such action is to run static code checks when a PR is raised from `task/**` branch to `develop` branch.
I tried to use the following workflow:

```yaml
name: validate PR raised from task/** branched to develop branch
on:
  pull_request:
    branches: [ task/** ]

  pull_request_target:
    branches: [ develop ]
  ...
```

this code is pushed to develop branch. but this triggers the workflow twice everytime a PR is raised or modified, indicating that the action is running with 'OR' configuration. I would like to run this workflow only once in 'AND' condition (i.e when the source branch is `task/**` AND target branch is `develop`)

For my first usecase, it is very important that only internal devs can trigger the generate build. so is that possible to run the actions for specific target and source branch?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can trigger the workflow for a pull request to the base branch and further refine the jobs to be run based on the head branch. Therefore, you can use the information available in [`github.head_ref`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts#github-context) and evaluate it in the [`if` conditional](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idif). As a result, the job gets skipped whenever the expression does not match. Here are the two workflows that match your description:

**build-sdk.yml**

```yaml
name: Build-SDK

on:
  pull_request:
    branches: [ master ]

jobs:
  build-sdk:
    if: github.head_ref == 'develop'
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest  
    steps:
      - run: echo "Build SDK..."
```

**validate.yml:**

```yaml
name: Validate

on:
  pull_request:
    branches: [ develop ]

jobs:
  validate:
    if: startsWith(github.head_ref, 'task/')
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest  
    steps:
      - run: echo "Validate..."
```

Comment: a small additional question in similar context : is it possible to combine both of the checks? like `if (branch is master && head is develop) OR (branch is develop && head is task/**)` then run the check? basically can i skip the `on` condition altogether and write the tests in `if(...)` condition?

Comment: @anshsachdeva Yes, this is possible by omitting the branch names in the `on` block and then combining the checks in the `if` conditional. The information in `github.base_ref` can be used to know the base branch.

Comment: Thanks, thats an intelligent approach @Matt